# Ajax load "Comments" onclick

Tags: jquery, ajax

i need some help here, ive got a database: "ID | PLZ | Country | Author | Comment"

With Jquery i managed to show/Hide the "Comment" field.

Now Im tryin to load the Comments with ajax onclick, so if u Click on the "Show comments" button, ajax should load the comment from the specific id.

I know I need to change also the jquery code to get the right comment from the right id, but i don't know how to do is.

Heres my Code:

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".productDescription").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();
        $(".hide_show").hide();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.productDescription').slideToggle();
         $(this).parent().find(".show_hide").hide();
        $(this).parent().find(".hide_show").show();
    });

 $('.hide_show').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.productDescription').slideToggle();
         $(this).parent().find(".show_hide").show();
        $(this).parent().find(".hide_show").hide();

    });

});

</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM ufo";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
    {

echo '
<div class="product clearfix">
    <h4>ID:'.$row->id.'|PLZ:'.$row->PLZ.'|Country:'.$row->Country.'</h4>
    <a href="#" class="show_hide">Show Comments</a>
    <a href="#" class="hide_show">Hide Comments</a>
    <div class="productDescription">
       <p>Comment:'.$row->Comment.'</p>
    </div>
</div>
<br>';

    }

?>
```

I'd appreciate that if someone could help me.

So long

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a quick example. You didn't provide a view so I just made up names to things.

```
$(".someButton").click(function(){
    $.get("/urlToMethod?id=" + idAssociatedWithButton,function(result){
        //do stuff with result
    })
})
```

Basically when your button is clicked it will fire the code inside. Inside the click I have a get call that will call upon some web method at a specified URL that takes in an ID. So a url could be /home/getComment?id=24. This means its calling a method called getComment and passing in a variable called id with the value of 24. With that you could get your comment data from your DB. The result variable inside the function of the get call is what is returned from your get method.

Here is more info on ajax calls with Jquery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. 
There are many ways to do it, this is just one way to get your started.

Comment: hey there, thanks for your reply, do i have now to call a .php file that fetches the comments? Live-Demo: http://www.twitch-smileys.com/ufo/

Comment: Yea, essentially you call a php method via url and in that php you call the database. I'm not to familiar with php so can't help you on how to structure it but im sure there are many examples around the web.